# How to activate normal search as you type focus for bootstrap select?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using bootstrap selectpicker in a project currently. The issue I am facing is it shifts the focus on the option on every key-stroke and begins a new search for each letter typed. For example if I have a select with option 1 to 20. Typing 1 and 2 even in quick succession will first shift focus to 1 followed by 2. I want the focus to shift to 12 instead.

I have explored the live-search option, but they take it to one more undesired level of hiding the unmatched options.

```
<select data-container="body" name="dt_239461" id="dt_239461ID">
    <option value="00">Day</option>
    <option value="01">01</option
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option> 
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option> 
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option> 
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option> 
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option> 
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option> 
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option> 
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option> 
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option> 
    <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<script src="/javascript/takesurvey/bootstrap-select.js">
<script>
     $(element).selectpicker();
</script>
```

Comment: This functionality belongs to the `select` element and is not specific to `bootstrap-select`. You are going to have to make this yourself if you really want it. Because this is not native behavior, it is not very user friendly. So unless you are the only user you might want to think about skipping this altogether.

Comment: Unfortunately that is what the user expectation is. We went with kendo select plugin initially, but it was not compatible with the jquery version we are using. This suited us in every possible way and somehow this issue went unnoticed until now.